# T-SQL : generate combination of numbers and save into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have the query that generates all possible combinations of 6 numbers in the range from 1 to 90.

However it stops working after some time generating the following error:

> An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Is there a way around this and how to save result to a table (not a temp table)?

```
WITH Numbers(N) AS 
(
    SELECT number
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'P'
      AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 90
)
SELECT *
FROM Numbers N1
JOIN Numbers N2 ON N2.N > N1.N
JOIN Numbers N3 ON N3.N > N2.N
JOIN Numbers N4 ON N4.N > N3.N
JOIN Numbers N5 ON N5.N > N4.N
JOIN Numbers N6 ON N6.N > N5.N
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This will generate zillions of rows.

Comment: I’m trying to get a table with all possible 6 out of 90 combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to populate your table a step at a time, increasing the value of the first column by 1 on each iteration.

Prerequisites:

1. Decide on the datatypes of the columns. The values are between 1-90 and they fit in tinyint (1 byte) not null. 6 columns = 6 bytes
2. Create a unique clustered index, since the combination of the columns is unique. A heap would add 8bytes overhead for the RID and a non-unique clustered index 4bytes for the uniquefier (and all six columns are just 6 bytes)
3. provision the db (free space + recovery model):
   (Six columns x 1 byte + ~8bytes row overhead) x 620mil = ~9-10GB of free space/storage in the database and minimize the overhead of datafile(s) auto-growing.
   If possible, better change the recovery model of the db to simple (to prevent log out of space errors).

You could also consider page compression for the "numbers" table, if space usage is of importance (and there is enough cpu for the added cost later on).

Create the numbers table:

```
create table dbo.numstable
(
a tinyint not null,
b tinyint not null,
c tinyint not null,
d tinyint not null,
e tinyint not null,
f tinyint not null,
constraint pknumstable primary key clustered(a,b,c,d,e,f)
);

go
```

And populate it, one col "a" value at a time:

```
declare @maxa int = (select isnull(max(a), 0)+1 from dbo.numstable);
select @maxa = case when @maxa <= 85 then @maxa end;

declare @Numbers table (N tinyint primary key clustered);
insert into @Numbers(N) 
select rownum --cast?
from
(
select top (90) row_number() over(order by rand()) as rownum
from master.dbo.spt_values
) as r
where rownum >= @maxa;

insert into dbo.numstable with (tablock)
(a,b,c,d,e,f) 
SELECT N1.N as a, N2.N as b, N3.N as c, N4.N as d, N5.N as e, N6.N as f
FROM @Numbers N1
JOIN @Numbers N2 ON N2.N > N1.N
JOIN @Numbers N3 ON N3.N > N2.N
JOIN @Numbers N4 ON N4.N > N3.N
JOIN @Numbers N5 ON N5.N > N4.N
JOIN @Numbers N6 ON N6.N > N5.N
where N1.N = @maxa
order by N1.N, N2.N, N3.N, N4.N, N5.N, N6.N;
go 85 --iterate 85 times
```

If an error occurs during population, remediate and execute the population script (as is) again.

If the throughput is around 15mil rows/minute (worst case), it will take ~40 minutes to fully populate the table.

When querying the table, you could "leverage" the nature of the data/values:

```
--instead of ...
select count(*)
from dbo.numstable
where c = 7
and e = 44;

--...better...
select count(*)
from dbo.numstable
where a  in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
and b in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
and c = 7
and e = 44;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is too long for a comment.

The number of rows that your query generates is just overwhelming. All possible combinations of 6 numbers between 1 and 90 evalues as `90 ^ 6` rows.

```
select power(cast(90 as real), 6) res

|          res |
| -----------: |
| 531441000000 |
```

That's more than 500 billion rows: obviously, this will exhaust the resources of your database server. Throwing hardware at it is not likely to make this possible. You should be rethinking what you are trying to do.

Comment: . . Actually, there are no repeats and the tuples are unique, so it is "only" 622,614,630 (90*89*88*87*86*85/6!).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I commented about the problem statement rather than the query itself - which, indeed, generates less rows (don't know what OP wants actually). I guess that 600 millions still qualifies as overwhelming though...

Comment: Last time I saw someone trying to do this was to generate all combinations for lottery purposes ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯